# How to re-order columns in data frame without losing values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have excel spreadsheets of results that a new column is added to each year. I want to use Pandas to select key columns from the spreadsheets and create a table that shows the last X years of results. My code runs, and the columns with text in appear to swap round as expected, but the numeric data is lost and replaced with NaNs.

From solutions to related issues on stackoverflow etc. it looks as though I should send a list of the required columns to the reindex method for dataframes.

```py
def yearTable2(filename='5years.xlsx',SheetName='PartA',interactive=True,A_year=2018,nyears=3,debug=False):
    """Outputs latex code of table of nyears years of results for a given part's
    module results
    Input:filename is the excel file with the data in, 
    sheetname contains the data for the part to be tablularised
    A_year is the current academic year"""
    xl=pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    df=xl.parse(SheetName)
    df2=df.round(1) # rounds numeric data to 1 decimal place
    if debug: print(df.head())
    #Have data in df2, it probably has more years of data than really needed 
    # extract just the needed ones
    # Build up list of column names in required order
    column_list=["Module Name","Module Code"] # these are standard
    # now generate the years required
    for year in list(range(A_year,A_year-nyears,-1)):
        list_item=str(year*1)
        column_list.append(list_item)
    print(column_list)
    df3=df2.reindex(columns=column_list)
    return (df3) # outputs pretty Jupyter table
```

I call this with:`yearTable2(filename='Test.xlsx',SheetName='PartC',debug=True)`

where Test.xlsx is an example file that has the following content:

```
|Module Code|Module Name|2013|2014|2015|2016|2017|2018|
______________________________________________________
|abc        |Harry      | 23 | 45 | 32 | 54 | 56 | 12 |
|fgr        |Jannice    | 28 | 65 | 21 | 34 | 21 | 54 |
```

I am expecting to get the following columns: Module Name, Module Code, 2018, 2017, 2016

The first two columns are fine, but the numeric (year) columns just contain NaNs

```
    Module Name Module Code 2018    2017    2016
0   Harry        abc         NaN    NaN     NaN
1   Jannice      fgr         NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Why are you using `df.reindex()` and not simply `df=df[column_list]`?

Comment: I'd tried that early on, got an error and then turned to searches which turned up using the reindex method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
list_item=str(year*1)
```

Write:

```
list_item=year
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd foolishly assumed that the column titles were strings.